# Google app script -Get the value of first google form response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have below code that give me the last response submitted from a form.
But this code gives me the values of all the questions in a form but I need the value only for the first question. I tried to use the below code but it is not working. Can someone help with that issue?

```js
const item = form.getItems()[0];

function getArrayOfLastSubmissionsAnswers() {
var allQuestions,i,itemType,L,thisAnswer,thisQuestion,thisSubmissionsAnswers,number_of_submissions;
   //Define all variables without assigning a value - value at this point
   //is undefined

number_of_submissions = FormApp.openById('your_Form_ID').getResponses().length;
allQuestions = FormApp.openById('your_Form_ID').getResponses()[number_of_submissions - 1].getItemResponses();

L = allQuestions.length;//How many questions are there in the Form
thisSubmissionsAnswers = [];//Create an empty array for answers

for (i=0;i<L;i++) {//Loop through all the questions in this Form submission
thisQuestion = allQuestions[i];//Get this question

itemType = thisQuestion.getItem().getType();

if (itemType === FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {
continue;//keep looping
    };

thisAnswer = thisQuestion.getResponse();//Get the answer
Logger.log(i + " - " + thisAnswer); 

thisSubmissionsAnswers.push(thisAnswer);//add answer to the array
  };

Logger.log("thisSubmissionsAnswers: " + thisSubmissionsAnswers); 

return thisSubmissionsAnswers; 
};
```

Comment: If you use the onFormSubmit trigger for a spreadsheet and allow e to be the argument then e.values[1] is the answer to the first question.

Comment: how do i select only the first column in this script I dont want to use the onform submit trigger

Comment: The first column of what?

Comment: the form has 10 questions and this code returns the value for all 10 questions i want this code to return the value of first question

Comment: try return thisSubmissionsAnswers[0];

Comment: Yes I tried adding [0] in logger .log and return. Still returning answers for all the 10 questions    Logger.log("thisSubmissionsAnswers: " + thisSubmissionsAnswers[0]); 

return thisSubmissionsAnswers[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This essentially the same script and  it runs for me on a sample form:

```
function getArrayOfLastSubmissionsAnswers() {
  const form = FormApp.openById("1-qF-mkbJjmWB6NcC6iwnUZSqjWdroh3Y5fd2QsJapS4");
  var as = [];
  form.getResponses()[form.getResponses().length - 1].getItemResponses().map(q => {
    if(q.getItem()  == FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {
      return;
    }
    as.push(q.getResponse());
  });
   Logger.log(as.slice(0,1));
  return as.slice(0,1);
}
```

It returns an array of one element the answer the to first question

This one returns the answer to the first question

```
function getArrayOfLastSubmissionsAnswers() {
  const form = FormApp.openById("formid");
  var as = [];
  form.getResponses()[form.getResponses().length - 1].getItemResponses().map(q => {
    if(q.getItem()  == FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {
      return;
    }
    as.push(q.getResponse());
  });
   Logger.log(as[0]);
  return as[0];
};
```